# Intellij IDEA failed to run

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, intellij-idea-2016

I get an error every time I run my IDEA, seems like it is because I use 64 bit but running the IDEA of 32 bit. From what I've searched, it refers me to use idea64.exe, but where can I find it?

[image]

Comment: did you check your JAVA_HOME path in system path? may be that denoted 32 bit java path.

Comment: @NeErAjKuMaR I have checked it, my JAVA_HOME refers to the jdk home without bin

Comment: that jdk is 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: When you install IntelliJ IDEA there is a question if you want to download 32-bit JDK. Make sure you've enabled this checkbox. Also only add 32-bit launcher shortcut.

Comment: @NeErAjKuMaR how do I check it ?

Comment: Enter command 
1) java -d32
2) java -d64
that command gave you output means you installed that in your system

Comment: @NeErAjKuMaR thank you for the information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA is now bundled with only 64-bit Java version. 32-bit JDK is not provided. If you install on the 32-bit system, there will be a checkbox in the installer to automatically download and configure 32-bit Runtime for IntelliJ IDEA.

Installer also has the options to create both 32-bit and 64-bit executable shortcuts. If you want to run 64-bit version, use `IDEA_HOME\bin\idea64.exe`.

Or you can just [download this runtime version](https://bintray.com/jetbrains/intellij-jdk/download_file?file_path=jbrex8u152b915.9_windows_x86.tar.gz) and unpack it into `IDEA_HOME` directory (so that you have `IDEA_HOME\jre`). Make sure to start IntelliJ IDEA with `bin\idea.exe` instead of `bin\idea64.exe`. This will start IntelliJ IDEA in 32-bit mode.

Another option is to [download](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html) the `.zip` version for Windows, it has both 32-bit and 64-bit runtimes. Then you can use either `bin\idea.exe` or `bin\idea64.exe` to run (if you are on the 64-bit system):

[image: download zip]

Answer (score 0):

At least the answer to your question

> it refers me to use idea64.exe, but where can I find it?

is quite straightforward:

Under the folder you installed IntelliJ IDEA into, e.g.
`C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2\` there is a subfolder `bin\` where you find `idea64.exe`

Answer (score -1):

It is complaining because it cannot find a 32-bit JDK on your computer? Do you have the JDK installed?
If not, follow this [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/windows_jdk_install.html#CHDEBCCJ) or use [this video](https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=How%20to%20install%20java%20jdk&view=detail&mid=CC39819C5B1722E98B22CC39819C5B1722E98B22&FORM=VIRE). You will probably need to install the 32-bit version if you want to use the 32-bit IDE.

Comment: Actually I am complaining because I cannot launch my IDEA and I am not sure what is the problem

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I said it is complaining as in the IDE is complaining about not having the proper JDK, not that you are complaining.

Comment: I believe the problem is you having a 64-bit jdk but a 32-bit IDE. As such the IDE (probably) would complain about that and not launch.

Comment: Yes Im having jdk of 64 bit