# intellij idea failed to create JVM error code -1

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jvm, java-home

I have intellij-idea installed. Although I have set JAVA_HOME environment variable referring to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45" but when I try to run it, I end up with the following error:

```
failed to create JVM: error code -1. JVM path: "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.2\jre64\" if you have a 64-bit jdk installed, define a JAVA_HOME variable in Computer> system variables> system settings> environment variables.
```

Windows 7_ 64-bit

Comment: Are you on a 32bit OS ?

Comment: Please specify your windows version

Comment: See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544879 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/45309479/104891.

Comment: Windows 7 ultimate service pack1 _ 64-bit operating system

Comment: You can manually edit the idea.exe.vmoptions property file to specify the exact java path and try again.

Comment: simply try java -version on command prompt, if it is not detected, then set the java path and make sure it works fine in command prompt, then try with ide.

Comment: I removed -Xmx1024m from ea -Xmx1024m from idea64.exe.vmoptions file. And it worked.

Answer (score 12):

My workaround was to go to C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3\idea64.exe vmoptions file and delete the whole content. The error disappeared and IntelliJ started normally.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Previously it was stored in ~/.IdealC20XX.X but starting from 2020 version they moved it to AppData path.

Comment: thank you kind person, spend an hour trying to find a solution

Comment: Had the same problem with Pycharm, after deleting the vmoptions file , it worked

Answer (score 8):

Note that there are 2 .vmoptions files. There is the one in the bin directory and an override in 
    %HOMEPATH%\IntelliJIdea\config

For me the answer was to remove -Xmx and -Xms options from the override file.

Answer (score 6):

Please check your `phpstorm64.exe.vmoptions` file located at `bin` folder and remove option

`-XX:+UseG1GC`

Comment: Thanks! Although this specific -XX option wasn't present, I resolved the issue by deleting vmoptions files

Answer (score 6):

it is not a JAVA_HOME issue, you no doubt have touched the *.vmoptions files in bin folder. if you have entered the licence sever in the *.vmpotions file, notice that it should be like this "-javaagent:C:\Program Files....." don't forget to include "-javaagent:" at the beginning of the license server ;)

Comment: I can't find that file; where is it?

Comment: @GuillaumeF. look inside C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.2\bin

Answer (score 6):

The file may be corrupted after a bad manipulation.
Just copy and paste the idea{64}.exe.vmoptions from 
%IntelliJ installation path%/bin to %User IntelliJ data path%/config.
For example : 
Copy "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/bin/idea64.exe.vmoptions" and paste into "C:/Users/HP/.IntelliJIdea2019.2/config"

Answer (score 2):

I've been using IntelliJ for some time and this issue popped up sometime ago for me too. The issue is with a "VMOPTIONS" file. **C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans** Go to this location and inside you'll find a VMOPTIONS file. Delete it. Now run the Application and it should work. This VMOPTIONS file is infact a copy of the original VMOPTION file located else where but which can also override the default VMOPTIONS. So deleting this copy with some invalid options inside fixes the problem.

If a VMOPTIONS file doesn't exist in the above path, Go to this location **C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition xxxx.x.x\bin** and run the **idea.bat** file. Not the exe file. This should fix any and all other problems and let you open the application with out getting that error.

Answer (score 1):

You might have the JRE_HOME environment variable set in your system. Remove that and try again. It generally overwrites the JAVA_HOME variable.

Comment: I didn't have JRE_HOME variable in my environment variables

Answer (score 1):

I am just copy file "phpstorm64.exe.vmoptions" from  C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2019.3.1\bin and paste it(replace) in C:\Users\{{your username}}\.PhpStorm2019.3\config
It works fine for me..

Answer (score 0):

I got such error when adding JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS in environment variables. Try to rename this variable to JAVA_OPTS restart IDE and rename again to JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS. Or simply delete JAVA_TOOLS_OPTIONS if it is not required

Answer (score 0):

You can find default vmoptions file of windows 64bit version of it in :

C:\Users{user}\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PhpStorm..\phpstorm64.exe.vmoptions

You can reinstall phpstorm as well ,it's quick.

Answer (score 0):

I simply removed JAVA_HOME from system variable then again added and saved.

Restart IntelliJ again. Worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine with **Webstorm**

1. **JAVA_HOME**. Watch this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IJ-PJbvJBGs)
2. **Delete .vmoptions file**. It contains in:

- C:\Program Files\WebStorm 2021.3\bin
- C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\WebStorm2021.3 OR C:\Users\%USER%\.somewhere

Answer (score 0):

I had added
`-T 6C clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true` lines. Then I removed them, program is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove vmoptions file from C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IdeaIC2021.1

It worked for me once I removed the file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Start cmd.exe
2. `cd %APPDATA%\..\Local\Programs\IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate\bin`
3. `idea.bat`
4. Output was:

   ```
   Invalid ReservedCodeCacheSize=3048M. Must be at most 2048M.
   Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
   Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
   ```
5. Indeed, there is the environment variable `ACC` which contains `-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=3048m`.
6. It turned out that `%APPDATA%\..\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2023.3\idea64.exe.vmoptions` contained that string. Changing `3048m` to `2048m` made IntelliJ starting again.

Answer (score -2):

try to launch idea64.exe from the cmd and see if it works